# submit button with background image in internet explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

On [this site](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/), I have a search form whose submit button has a background image

[image]

But when I view the site in IE8, the image doesn't appear.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to persuade IE8 to show the image (that doesn't cause it to disappear in other broswers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the image is present, but barely visible. Try setting the height and width of the `input`. This makes the image visible for me:

```
.searchform INPUT[type='submit'] {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in IE8 in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VF5Pc/1/)

I didn't see anywhere in your code that the background image is actually set in IE8. It shows in Chrome. Are you using multiple style sheets based on browser? Or browser specific rules in your styles?

Comment: The BG image is certainly being set in IE 8

Comment: I looked at the source for IE8 and the background parameter isn't set. It should be listed in .searchform of the "bundle-core_head.css file, but I'm not seeing it there.