# background-image: url() for input not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with a form in it. I am trying to add an image to a button. So far, the image for the button is working/displaying in firefox and chrome. But in IE8 its just displaying the normal input button. Even the transparency and other properties are not working. Can anyone please suggest any solution, or correct me if I am wrong cause I am just a noob in all this web thing. Thank you!

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<html>

    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "assets/css/style.css" %}">
    </head>

    <body>
    <header>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="{% static "assets/images/google.png" %}" width="202.5" class="logo"/></a>
            </div>
            <div id="form">
                <form action="/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email">

                    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">

                    <input type="submit" value=" "/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <footer>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="image">
                <div>
                    <a href="/assets/image/test.png"></a>
                </div
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

style.css:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


body{
    background:#3effbd;
}

#main {
    background-color:#3B5998;
    width:1000%;
    height:90px;
}

.logo {
    border:none;
    top:24px;
    left:247px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.login li{
position:relative;
top: -10px;
left: 900px;
display:inline;
}

input[type=submit]{
    border:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 57px;
    height: 26px;
    background-image: url(../images/button.png);
}

.label {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [submit button with background image in internet explorer 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332783/submit-button-with-background-image-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: Is that width @ 1000% an typo in #main?

Comment: @putvande this is a different issue altogether. This is for styling the actual submit input rather than adding an icon to an input. For some reason the way IE8 responds to these two issues is different, hence I'd say this is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the entire code on my local drive but was working fine in IE8!

However instead of using input type submit try this:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no value in the button - it won't show anything. add `&nbsp;` in the value or use the good 'ol indent:-999999 with a value.

also add this CSS

```
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation and I have now found a resolution, that works perfectly. It's been tested on a Virtual Machine running Win XP & IE8, to be 100% it works.

Here's is what I found:

In developer tools on IE8 input[type=submit] was being associated with the submit button however, none of the associated css rules were actually kicking in. To prove this I changed them in dev tools and even removed them. The button remained the same.

So, it seems that the rule is attached but the properties don't get implemented. The simple fix for this is to give your button a class and then add this class to your button rules in css like so:

```
<input type="submit" value=" " class="btn"/>
```

then add the class to your css:

```
input[type=submit], .btn{
border:none;
background-color: transparent;
overflow: hidden;
cursor: pointer;
width: 57px;
height: 26px;
background-image: url(../images/button.png);
}
```

You should now see the rule properties taking effect.

If not you should try changing:

```
background-image: url(../images/button.png);
```

to

```
background: url(../images/button.png);
```

as there are reports of images needing to be referenced as background the first time they are used in a css file.